# Combinar array de objetos con array sencillo

Tags: php

Buen dia,

Tengo una clase que me consulta un cliente de acuerdo al nombre

```
class Cliente extends Conexion{

public function __construct(){    
            //creamos la instancia de un objeto de tipo conexion
            $this->conexion = new Conexion();
            $this->conexion = $this->conexion->conectarse();
        }

public function consultarClientePorNombre(string $nombre)
        {
           $sql="SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre = ?";            
           $arrWhere = array($nombre);            
           $query = $this->conexion->prepare($sql);            
           $query->execute($arrWhere);  
       
           //aqui el cliente sale bien, con su codigo y nombre
           $request = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

           //extraigo solo el codigo para consultar sus CEDIS en otra tabla MySql
           $codigo_cliente = $request['codigo'];

           //el cliente puede tener varios CEDIS
           $consulta_cedis="SELECT * FROM cedis WHERE codigo_cliente = $codigo_cliente";
           $execute = $this->conexion->query($consulta_cedis);

        //hasta aca todo funciona bien, me trae los 2,3,4,5 cedis etc que tenga el cliente
           $query = $execute->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);              
        }
}
```

el array del cliente me lo arroja asi

```
{"id":"1","codigo":"14","nombre":"JUAN"}
```

el array de los CEDIS me los arroja asi, para el caso del cliente codigo 1, segun veo es un array de objetos

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [codigo_cliente] => 1 [nombre] => FURJAL ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [codigo_cliente] => 1 [nombre] => PARAMO ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [codigo_cliente] => 1 [nombre] => NEVADO ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 4 [codigo_cliente] => 1 [nombre] => CAFETAL ) )
```

la pregunta es, como combino ambas cosas de tal manera que me quede asi

```
{"id":"1","codigo":"14","nombre":"JUAN","cedi":"FURJAL","cedi":"PARAMO","cedi":"NEVADO","cedi":"CAFETAL"}
```

Comment: Te recomendaría que armes tu JSON en una sola consulta. Según la versión de MySQL puedes usar funciones propias de SGBD para tales fines, y si tu versión es antigua, lo puedes hacer concatenando, armando un JSON a mano. La ventaja es doble: evitas hacer dos consultas a la BD, y neutralizas el grave fallo de seguridad que tienes en tu segunda consulta. Y además, estarías leyendo un sólo resultado, que sería tu JSON ya listo para usar allí donde haga falta.

Comment: @A.Cedano me puees explicar por que es un fallo de seguridad?? en que parte?? gracias!!!

Comment: Si bien el dato que usas aquí: `$consulta_cedis="SELECT * FROM cedis WHERE codigo_cliente = $codigo_cliente";` proviene de la anterior consulta, hay un fallo de seguridad ahí. Es cierto que primero tendrían que inyectarte código en una inserción con respecto a `codigo_cliente` (lo cual no es imposible), y ese dato inyectado podría causar estragos en tu BD puesto que lo pasas directamente a `query()`, **nunca deberías hacer eso con valores dinámicos, vengan de donde vengan**. Deberías preparar **también** esa consulta. Además las consultas preparadas son más rápidas.

Comment: @A.Cedano ok, en conclusion, si uso el tema de prepare, es mas rapido y me ayuda a prevenir SQL injection, muchas gracias por la ayuda!  trataré entocnes de hacer todo en una consulta como dices

Comment: Yo no entiendo... cuando dices "El array del cliente me lo arroja así" y pones un objeto, y al final con la respuesta que esperas, también hay algo raro, también es un objeto y se repite la clave "cedi"  (Cosa que en teoría no debería ser valido): `"cedi":"FURJAL","cedi":"PARAMO", "cedi": ....`
Puedes aclarar esos puntos?

Comment: quizas sería mas lógico algo como `{"id":"1","codigo":"14","nombre":"JUAN","cedis":["FURJAL", "PARAMO", "NEVADO","CAFETAL"] }`